# How to get more information about an intent?

Tags: android, android-intent

How can I extract all information about an intent? Like action, extras, bundles etc.

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Log.d(Tag.getTag(this), (/*What shall I add here?*/));
```

Comment: @snicolas Thank you. I get `12-11 19:08:30.983: D/com.simple.search.com.simple.search.SimpleSearch(4340): data :Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider/tests flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.simple.search/.SimpleSearch (has extras) }`. How can I extract information about extras?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`intent.getAction()`, `intent.getData()`, `intent.getExtras()`, and maybe others. All of these are documented in the [`Intent` class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Comment: Thanks, but `intent.getExtras()` requires argument string - name of the extra. How can I determine that?

Comment: That depends on the extras you've  added to the `Intent` before calling `startActivity(intent)`. 
You put an extra in with a `key` and a `value`. This `value` can be retrieved by calling `Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String text = extras.getString("yourkey");`
More info about how to put and get extras from intents can be found here: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html#explicitintents

Comment: @felix What if I don't know the value of yourkey? Is it still possible to extract the information from the bundle?

Comment: @sander-vant-veer Thanks. What if I don't know the value of yourkey? Is it still possible to extract the information from the bundle?

Comment: @BinoyBabu if you would look at the docs, you would see that `getExtras()` does not require any argument. It returns a `Bundle`. If you would look at the `Bundle` documentation, you would see it has a `keySet()` method, which returns all the keys in the bundle. From there, you can use the `get()` method to get the values (or the `get[type]` methods).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using toString() method, you can see something like,
     Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.test/.TestDeleteActivity }

What I suggest is, if you want details about your running Intent, use the appropriate methods. As an example by using getPackage() method you can retrieve the application package name this Intent is limited to. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) contains all the methods you can use with Intent class.

If you want to pass some data from one Intent to another, use the Bundle class. This [link](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/how-to-get-the-content-that-user-type-in-a-edittext-field-in-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android/) will show you a simple example of how to use Bundle class.

Comment: Thanks. All I need to know is if there is a way to extract data from bundle without the key.